# How to Join Two MySQL query into a single array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql query as follows

```
$sql1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM manualp WHERE client_id=75 AND date between '$currentdate' and '$prevdate' ");

$sql2=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM manualp WHERE client_id=75 order by date DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Is there any way i can join them together ? and get them in a array . For example 
Both query are joined into $sql3 . I would like to post result having value $sql2 showing last

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3)) { 

POST RESULTS HERE
}
```

Comment: Why not use an SQL UNION?

Comment: Can you give me an example ? I am not familiar with it

Comment: Well, why not research it?  Plenty of examples out there showing unions.

Comment: I will . Thanks for the info :D

Comment: @Devon 

SELECT * FROM manualp WHERE client_id=75 order by date DESC LIMIT 1 UNION SELECT * FROM manualp WHERE client_id=74 order by date DESC LIMIT 1  

But it gives #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY , any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, because you're using ORDER BY and LIMIT in your query, you actually need to wrap that second query in a subquery to perform a UNION.

```
SELECT * FROM manualp WHERE client_id=75 AND date between '$currentdate' and '$prevdate' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM manualp WHERE client_id=75 order by date DESC LIMIT 1) t1
```

Comment: That solves it. But main issue is , The data from second part is repetitive with the 1st part . When i am running the while loop , data from 2nd query shows everywhere with the data from the 1st one .

Comment: Well yes, that'd be the point of a union in SQL, joining them all as one result set.  Your question wasn't clear that you needed them separate as well.   If you need them separate then a SQL UNION isn't the way to go.  There are a lot of ways you could do that in PHP, one being add all the results to the same array..